# How to restore initial value in DataTrigger ExitActions after an animation completes?

Tags: c#, wpf, animation

I am extremely frustrated with something that should be relatively straight forward.  I have an alarm, whenever the status changes I want to animate the text scale to increase in size.  This should repeat 3 times and then stop leaving the text at its **original** value.

I have looked at every example I could find and tried several different implementations without any effect.  Once the animation stops the text is left large.  Why does it seem like nothing in my DataTrigger.ExitActions is working firing?

```
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" FontSize="22" Text="{Binding Path=DisplayName, IsAsync=True}" Padding="2,0,2,0">
    <TextBlock.RenderTransform> 
        <ScaleTransform x:Name="scale" /> 
    </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
<TextBlock.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Value, Converter={StaticResource AlarmConverter}, IsAsync=True}" Value="true">
                <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="NewAlarm" />                                                     
                        <BeginStoryboard Name="NewAlarm">
                            <Storyboard RepeatBehavior="3x" >
                                <DoubleAnimation  Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"
                                                  Duration="00:00:02" 
                                                  From="1"
                                                  To="1.5"  />

                                 <DoubleAnimation  
                                                   Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"
                                                   Duration="00:00:02"
                                                   From="1" To="1.5"  />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <RemoveStoryboard  BeginStoryboardName="NewAlarm" />
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation  
                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"
                                    Duration="00:00:01" />

                                     <DoubleAnimation  
                                  Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"
                                  Duration="00:00:01" />
                                </Storyboard>
                             </BeginStoryboard>
                          </DataTrigger.ExitActions>
                       </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
           </TextBlock.Style>
       </TextBlock>
```

1. I tried using Autoreverse but I really don't like how the animation looks
2. I've tried with and without the  tag in the ExitActions.
3. I've tried setting From and To in the ExitAction animations
4. I've tries Setting just To in the ExitAction animations
   5  I've tried setting just Duration and no To in the ExitAction animations
   6  I've tried with and without the  tag in the EnterActions
5. I tried adding a third animation that started after the first two ended that would

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExitActions gets called when value returned from converter will be false but you want to remove the animation as soon as you are done with it.

This can be achieved by setting **[FillBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.fillbehavior(v=vs.110).aspx)** to **`Stop`** on your Storyboard which means you don't want an animation to hold its value after it reaches the end of its active period.

```
<Storyboard FillBehavior="Stop" RepeatBehavior="3x" >
    <DoubleAnimation  
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleX"
        Duration="00:00:02" 
        From="1"
        To="1.5"  />
    <DoubleAnimation  
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="RenderTransform.ScaleY"
        Duration="00:00:02"
        From="1" To="1.5"  />
</Storyboard>
```

With this in place you can get rid of ExitActions if not required.